2014 Subaru BRZ - U0073, C1234, C146c, C146e - ABS, TRAC, and parking brake light on
According to the repair manual it says to first check the fuses, and if they are fine then you need to replace the ABS modules. My fuses are fine so.. ABS module replacement it is.
They are very cheap on ebay, but the issue is I'm not sure if the computer is plug and play. Do I have to reprogram the used module?

Before replacing module it may be a good idea to check the integrety of any wiring and connectors that could throw these codes.

Unless you're using Subaru repair manuals, equivalent alldata.diy or Mitchell data (the latter two are equivalent if not direct reprints of Subaru manuals), aftermarket manuals may not have accurate info, especially about technical info related to abs, traction control and electronic stability control systems. Abs diagnosing, troubleshooting and repairs are not diy friendly and require factory manuals and familiarity with brake systems, including abs. At the least, info from Subaru BRZ forums may help.

I call it a manual but I'm using the Toyota Techstream for the Scion FRS, same exact car.

Received a new pump and module from ebay, they only sold them together. Made sure to buy one with exactly the same part number, despite coming from exact same car and exact same year, there were 3 different variations of the part number that I could find. Make sure to get the right one.
Disconnected battery, removed old computer (4 screws and it slides right out) and replaced with ebay one. Reconnected battery.
Turned the car on and no more lights, everything was perfect. Haven't scanned for codes yet, but seems all is well, no programming needed.

Congrats! Here's hoping all is well!
